# How to create a CVS repository in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

So obviously, I've installed the CVS integration plugin.

Still, I see nothing CVS-related in the available views.

What am I doing wrong here?

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-92.htm

Fails on step 1:

Creating a CVS repository location

> Prerequisite: A CVS server must already be configured on the host
>   machine to create a valid repository location in the Workbench.
>
> [no mention of any need to install the CVS plugin, but anyway....]
>
> To create a new repository location:
>
> Open the CVS Repositories view by selecting command link Window > Show
>   View > Other... > CVS > CVS Repositories. Alternatively, the CVS
>   Repositories view is also shown in the command link CVS Repository
>   Exploring perspective.

Neither of these are visible anywhere.  I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Apparently, this all works fine by default in Mars.  What did the Eclipse team break this time with the Neon release??

Comment: Have you tried it with the current release? What platform are you on? Which version of Java are you using? *How* did you install the CVS integration plug-in? Rather than quoting the documentation, exactly what steps are you trying?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.  I installed via the Eclipse Marketplace... was that wrong?   "java -version" says 1.8.0_144, but how is that relevant to Eclipse?

Comment: Depending on the version of Eclipse, different plug-ins might have required a newer version of Java than Eclipse in general. Doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Which entry in the Marketplace?